How to hide labels on X-Axis in Vegalite chart on excess amount of data
I want to create line chart but my data is huge so I want to hide some labels from then x-axis but marks should be visible for that x value field in chart
let's suppose I have 10 items in my data (try to explain with small data)
[{
    "Accuracy_percent": 100,
    "D15 - Rate": 100,
    "No of Removals": 0,
    "Period": "Dec 14 2020-Jan 10 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 100,
    "D15 - Rate": 100,
    "No of Removals": 0,
    "Period": "Dec 21 2020-Jan 17 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 100,
    "D15 - Rate": 100,
    "No of Removals": 0,
    "Period": "Dec 28 2020-Jan 24 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 100,
    "D15 - Rate": 100,
    "No of Removals": 0,
    "Period": "Jan 1 2021-Jan 31 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 100,
    "D15 - Rate": 100,
    "No of Removals": 473,
    "Period": "Jan 11 2021-Feb 7 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 99.42599,
    "D15 - Rate": 99.55423,
    "No of Removals": 418,
    "Period": "Jan 18 2021-Feb 14 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 98.92124,
    "D15 - Rate": 99.22762,
    "No of Removals": 153,
    "Period": "Jan 25 2021-Feb 21 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 98.28464,
    "D15 - Rate": 98.79925,
    "No of Removals": 282,
    "Period": "Feb 1 2021-Feb 28 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 97.6372,
    "D15 - Rate": 98.38467,
    "No of Removals": 430,
    "Period": "Feb 8 2021-Mar 7 2021"
  },
  {
    "Accuracy_percent": 97.62666,
    "D15 - Rate": 98.4651,
    "No of Removals": 167,
    "Period": "Feb 15 2021-Mar 14 2021"
  }]

I want to display those labels which have indexing (position) value divisible by 5, then only labels that should visible are Feb 15 2021-Mar 14 2021 and Jan 11 2021-Feb 7 2021 on x axis.
Editor link
on apply suggestion --
issue-labels are not uniformly disappear from x axis

just above X axis title
updated editor link 

Update using ceil:
 "axis": {
    "labelExpr": "ceil((data('source_0').length/100)*datum.index*100)%5 ==0? datum.label:''", "title":""
  }

A label expression enables you to have a label every 5 ticks:
"axis": {
        "labelExpr": "round((data('source_0').length/100)*datum.index*100)%5 ==0? datum.label:''"
      }


{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 100,
        "D15 - Rate": 100,
        "No of Removals": 0,
        "Period": "Dec 14 2020-Jan 10 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 100,
        "D15 - Rate": 100,
        "No of Removals": 0,
        "Period": "Dec 21 2020-Jan 17 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 100,
        "D15 - Rate": 100,
        "No of Removals": 0,
        "Period": "Dec 28 2020-Jan 24 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 100,
        "D15 - Rate": 100,
        "No of Removals": 0,
        "Period": "Jan 1 2021-Jan 31 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 100,
        "D15 - Rate": 100,
        "No of Removals": 473,
        "Period": "Jan 11 2021-Feb 7 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 99.42599,
        "D15 - Rate": 99.55423,
        "No of Removals": 418,
        "Period": "Jan 18 2021-Feb 14 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 98.92124,
        "D15 - Rate": 99.22762,
        "No of Removals": 153,
        "Period": "Jan 25 2021-Feb 21 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 98.28464,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.79925,
        "No of Removals": 282,
        "Period": "Feb 1 2021-Feb 28 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.6372,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.38467,
        "No of Removals": 430,
        "Period": "Feb 8 2021-Mar 7 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.62666,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.4651,
        "No of Removals": 167,
        "Period": "Feb 15 2021-Mar 14 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.32966,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.27109,
        "No of Removals": 563,
        "Period": "Feb 22 2021-Mar 21 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.3398,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.30746,
        "No of Removals": 696,
        "Period": "Mar 1 2021-Mar 31 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.35421,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.42846,
        "No of Removals": 252,
        "Period": "Mar 8 2021-Apr 4 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.20137,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.38189,
        "No of Removals": 418,
        "Period": "Mar 15 2021-Apr 11 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.22489,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.4905,
        "No of Removals": 477,
        "Period": "Mar 22 2021-Apr 18 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.23589,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.5417,
        "No of Removals": 383,
        "Period": "Apr 1 2021-Apr 25 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.15277,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.37232,
        "No of Removals": 421,
        "Period": "Apr 5 2021-Apr 30 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.23695,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.3784,
        "No of Removals": 513,
        "Period": "Apr 12 2021-May 9 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.32702,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.38504,
        "No of Removals": 410,
        "Period": "Apr 19 2021-May 16 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.22604,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.24978,
        "No of Removals": 929,
        "Period": "Apr 26 2021-May 23 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.27194,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.26452,
        "No of Removals": 690,
        "Period": "May 1 2021-May 31 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.04949,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.17364,
        "No of Removals": 463,
        "Period": "May 10 2021-Jun 6 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.8414,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.96773,
        "No of Removals": 550,
        "Period": "May 17 2021-Jun 13 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.64703,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.81734,
        "No of Removals": 584,
        "Period": "May 24 2021-Jun 20 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.41606,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.69364,
        "No of Removals": 829,
        "Period": "Jun 1 2021-Jun 30 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.3473,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.55034,
        "No of Removals": 306,
        "Period": "Jun 7 2021-Jul 4 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.08066,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.38773,
        "No of Removals": 564,
        "Period": "Jun 14 2021-Jul 11 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.9474,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.29611,
        "No of Removals": 782,
        "Period": "Jun 21 2021-Jul 18 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.91719,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.24984,
        "No of Removals": 490,
        "Period": "Jul 1 2021-Jul 25 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.89248,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.25823,
        "No of Removals": 648,
        "Period": "Jul 5 2021-Jul 31 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.21364,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.50693,
        "No of Removals": 663,
        "Period": "Jul 12 2021-Aug 8 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.54131,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.76797,
        "No of Removals": 479,
        "Period": "Jul 19 2021-Aug 15 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.67142,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.84335,
        "No of Removals": 336,
        "Period": "Jul 26 2021-Aug 22 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.9515,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.01446,
        "No of Removals": 682,
        "Period": "Aug 1 2021-Aug 31 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.02147,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.04621,
        "No of Removals": 463,
        "Period": "Aug 9 2021-Sep 5 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.05728,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.05106,
        "No of Removals": 287,
        "Period": "Aug 16 2021-Sep 12 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.10018,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.16641,
        "No of Removals": 435,
        "Period": "Aug 23 2021-Sep 19 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.0044,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.09912,
        "No of Removals": 574,
        "Period": "Sep 1 2021-Sep 26 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 97.09156,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.11735,
        "No of Removals": 524,
        "Period": "Sep 6 2021-Sep 30 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.89771,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.98016,
        "No of Removals": 691,
        "Period": "Sep 13 2021-Oct 10 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.7588,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.88531,
        "No of Removals": 477,
        "Period": "Sep 20 2021-Oct 17 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.79364,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.94437,
        "No of Removals": 346,
        "Period": "Sep 27 2021-Oct 24 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.73451,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.95361,
        "No of Removals": 444,
        "Period": "Oct 1 2021-Oct 31 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.68944,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.92553,
        "No of Removals": 316,
        "Period": "Oct 11 2021-Nov 7 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.75225,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.91962,
        "No of Removals": 452,
        "Period": "Oct 18 2021-Nov 14 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.68684,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.9432,
        "No of Removals": 386,
        "Period": "Oct 25 2021-Nov 21 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.46259,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.80871,
        "No of Removals": 488,
        "Period": "Nov 1 2021-Nov 30 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.53734,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.91808,
        "No of Removals": 471,
        "Period": "Nov 8 2021-Dec 5 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.56339,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.95498,
        "No of Removals": 465,
        "Period": "Nov 15 2021-Dec 12 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.37969,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.78635,
        "No of Removals": 498,
        "Period": "Nov 22 2021-Dec 19 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.49972,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.85502,
        "No of Removals": 269,
        "Period": "Dec 1 2021-Dec 26 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.53234,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.80909,
        "No of Removals": 262,
        "Period": "Dec 6 2021-Dec 31 2021"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.49622,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.76903,
        "No of Removals": 570,
        "Period": "Dec 13 2021-Jan 9 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.61475,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.84623,
        "No of Removals": 519,
        "Period": "Dec 20 2021-Jan 16 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.50777,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.80775,
        "No of Removals": 376,
        "Period": "Dec 27 2021-Jan 23 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.51397,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.86305,
        "No of Removals": 443,
        "Period": "Jan 1 2022-Jan 31 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.8067,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.05689,
        "No of Removals": 195,
        "Period": "Jan 10 2022-Feb 6 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.78122,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.08411,
        "No of Removals": 458,
        "Period": "Jan 17 2022-Feb 13 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.94704,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.21497,
        "No of Removals": 240,
        "Period": "Jan 24 2022-Feb 20 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.87418,
        "D15 - Rate": 98.15584,
        "No of Removals": 395,
        "Period": "Feb 1 2022-Feb 28 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.50681,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.96736,
        "No of Removals": 482,
        "Period": "Feb 7 2022-Mar 6 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.48524,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.97159,
        "No of Removals": 426,
        "Period": "Feb 14 2022-Mar 13 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.41431,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.86947,
        "No of Removals": 651,
        "Period": "Feb 21 2022-Mar 20 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.31962,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.7829,
        "No of Removals": 411,
        "Period": "Mar 1 2022-Mar 27 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.19373,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.72831,
        "No of Removals": 149,
        "Period": "Mar 7 2022-Mar 31 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.05978,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.57919,
        "No of Removals": 700,
        "Period": "Mar 14 2022-Apr 10 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.90772,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.47954,
        "No of Removals": 263,
        "Period": "Mar 21 2022-Apr 17 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.80158,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.38144,
        "No of Removals": 559,
        "Period": "Mar 28 2022-Apr 24 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.7704,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.23742,
        "No of Removals": 221,
        "Period": "Apr 1 2022-Apr 30 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.81006,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.26947,
        "No of Removals": 559,
        "Period": "Apr 11 2022-May 8 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.04956,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.48301,
        "No of Removals": 818,
        "Period": "Apr 18 2022-May 15 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.18634,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.6472,
        "No of Removals": 344,
        "Period": "Apr 25 2022-May 22 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.32877,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.8475,
        "No of Removals": 371,
        "Period": "May 1 2022-May 31 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.3275,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.80805,
        "No of Removals": 181,
        "Period": "May 9 2022-Jun 5 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.18271,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.6862,
        "No of Removals": 585,
        "Period": "May 16 2022-Jun 12 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.23673,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.71946,
        "No of Removals": 266,
        "Period": "May 23 2022-Jun 19 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.32514,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.77192,
        "No of Removals": 491,
        "Period": "Jun 1 2022-Jun 26 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.5455,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.98469,
        "No of Removals": 359,
        "Period": "Jun 6 2022-Jun 30 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.52781,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.97977,
        "No of Removals": 999,
        "Period": "Jun 13 2022-Jul 10 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.34721,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.82129,
        "No of Removals": 346,
        "Period": "Jun 20 2022-Jul 17 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.22644,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.66934,
        "No of Removals": 479,
        "Period": "Jun 27 2022-Jul 24 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.92619,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.45639,
        "No of Removals": 531,
        "Period": "Jul 1 2022-Jul 31 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.95999,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.43979,
        "No of Removals": 568,
        "Period": "Jul 11 2022-Aug 7 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.9185,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.43387,
        "No of Removals": 473,
        "Period": "Jul 18 2022-Aug 14 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.89297,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.48276,
        "No of Removals": 398,
        "Period": "Jul 25 2022-Aug 21 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.01685,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.54021,
        "No of Removals": 829,
        "Period": "Aug 1 2022-Aug 31 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.06576,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.60338,
        "No of Removals": 277,
        "Period": "Aug 8 2022-Sep 4 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.25371,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.77113,
        "No of Removals": 510,
        "Period": "Aug 15 2022-Sep 11 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.37833,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.79333,
        "No of Removals": 490,
        "Period": "Aug 22 2022-Sep 18 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.45563,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.84544,
        "No of Removals": 290,
        "Period": "Sep 1 2022-Sep 25 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.41918,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.81712,
        "No of Removals": 669,
        "Period": "Sep 5 2022-Sep 30 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.57803,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.89145,
        "No of Removals": 437,
        "Period": "Sep 12 2022-Oct 9 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.51249,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.85457,
        "No of Removals": 523,
        "Period": "Sep 19 2022-Oct 16 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.30555,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.78547,
        "No of Removals": 296,
        "Period": "Sep 26 2022-Oct 23 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.28801,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.78844,
        "No of Removals": 417,
        "Period": "Oct 1 2022-Oct 31 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.09762,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.65438,
        "No of Removals": 394,
        "Period": "Oct 10 2022-Nov 6 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.00441,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.66694,
        "No of Removals": 303,
        "Period": "Oct 17 2022-Nov 13 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.15067,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.67577,
        "No of Removals": 500,
        "Period": "Oct 24 2022-Nov 20 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.0806,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.61128,
        "No of Removals": 370,
        "Period": "Nov 1 2022-Nov 30 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.84787,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.4245,
        "No of Removals": 234,
        "Period": "Nov 7 2022-Dec 4 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.05024,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.53416,
        "No of Removals": 422,
        "Period": "Nov 14 2022-Dec 11 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.99459,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.49971,
        "No of Removals": 314,
        "Period": "Nov 21 2022-Dec 18 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.88872,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.42092,
        "No of Removals": 361,
        "Period": "Dec 1 2022-Dec 25 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.90108,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.52897,
        "No of Removals": 382,
        "Period": "Dec 5 2022-Dec 31 2022"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.50301,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.23053,
        "No of Removals": 680,
        "Period": "Dec 12 2022-Jan 8 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.6356,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.28337,
        "No of Removals": 325,
        "Period": "Dec 19 2022-Jan 15 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.71725,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.2763,
        "No of Removals": 418,
        "Period": "Dec 26 2022-Jan 22 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.94945,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.37109,
        "No of Removals": 439,
        "Period": "Jan 1 2023-Jan 31 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.19768,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.48553,
        "No of Removals": 289,
        "Period": "Jan 9 2023-Feb 5 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.15098,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.49427,
        "No of Removals": 455,
        "Period": "Jan 16 2023-Feb 12 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.99873,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.47169,
        "No of Removals": 375,
        "Period": "Jan 23 2023-Feb 19 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.02319,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.45191,
        "No of Removals": 743,
        "Period": "Feb 1 2023-Feb 28 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.896,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.40432,
        "No of Removals": 250,
        "Period": "Feb 6 2023-Mar 5 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.86846,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.42981,
        "No of Removals": 266,
        "Period": "Feb 13 2023-Mar 12 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.99813,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.52835,
        "No of Removals": 471,
        "Period": "Feb 20 2023-Mar 19 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.75428,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.42457,
        "No of Removals": 555,
        "Period": "Mar 1 2023-Mar 26 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.80497,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.46646,
        "No of Removals": 333,
        "Period": "Mar 6 2023-Mar 31 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.6862,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.45891,
        "No of Removals": 477,
        "Period": "Mar 13 2023-Apr 9 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.76438,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.517,
        "No of Removals": 358,
        "Period": "Mar 20 2023-Apr 16 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.91128,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.65528,
        "No of Removals": 388,
        "Period": "Mar 27 2023-Apr 23 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.80332,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.65391,
        "No of Removals": 627,
        "Period": "Apr 1 2023-Apr 30 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.69608,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.44774,
        "No of Removals": 493,
        "Period": "Apr 10 2023-May 7 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.33211,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.19074,
        "No of Removals": 365,
        "Period": "Apr 17 2023-May 14 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.17347,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.09568,
        "No of Removals": 483,
        "Period": "Apr 24 2023-May 21 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.3633,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.20102,
        "No of Removals": 481,
        "Period": "May 1 2023-May 31 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.53392,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.32128,
        "No of Removals": 108,
        "Period": "May 8 2023-Jun 4 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.86854,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.53964,
        "No of Removals": 432,
        "Period": "May 15 2023-Jun 11 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.92585,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.49174,
        "No of Removals": 347,
        "Period": "May 22 2023-Jun 18 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 95.82389,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.37759,
        "No of Removals": 343,
        "Period": "Jun 1 2023-Jun 25 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.03975,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.6111,
        "No of Removals": 310,
        "Period": "Jun 5 2023-Jun 30 2023"
      },
      {
        "Accuracy_percent": 96.0783,
        "D15 - Rate": 97.62362,
        "No of Removals": 533,
        "Period": "Jun 12 2023-Jul 9 2023"
      }
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Period",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {"field": "id"},
      "axis": {
        "labelExpr": "round((data('source_0').length/100)*datum.index*100)%5 ==0? datum.label:''"
      }
    },
    "y": {"field": "Accuracy_percent", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/1KPRrPW3.png


thanks it working but i want to know the explaining of these calculation

can i consider value after  % in labelExpr string as number of label i want disappaer

It is using a standard mod technique (% is a mod operator in javascript). If you break the expression up, you can see what each part returns in the axis to understand it.

it is not uniform means not disappearing equally in middle it disappear more then 5 using your suggesstion starting and ending is fine

I don't understand. Can you show the problem?

i update the question with image and new editor link

OK - try this instead which uses ceil. It works on the sample data (your new link doesn't work for me)

"axis": {
"labelExpr": "ceil((data('source_0').length/100)datum.index100)%5 ==0? datum.label:''", "title":""
}
